# iphone textfield focus to send field

Tags: iphone

hello all i have my four textfield for entering  password  If my password is "1 2 3 4", is there a way to automatically jump to the second box as soon as I enter "1" and so on and so forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a UITextViewDelegate to detect the input and then call becomeFirstResponder on the next text field.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make your class conform to UITesxtFieldDelegate and then use delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if(texField == textfield1)
    {
        if([textfield1.text isEqualToString: @"1"])
        {
             [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
             [textfield2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }      
    }
    else if(texField == textfield2) 
    ...... // write similar code
}
```

Text field calls this method whenever user enters some text or delete text from textfield. Also you need to set in your viewdidload method `textfield1.delegate=self;` for each textfield you need to call this method. For further  details read doc for [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:).